# Performance consideration, please which option is better

Tags: mysql

Which one is better - Using mysql aggregate function COUNT to return number of selected occurrence or manually counting and inserting the count into a field during insertion operation? Considering that COUNT function searches the table or an index and groups the result, while in manual counting, I would just retrieve the  field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do it manually

- You do extra work that is not required
- You've to remember to do it for each insert and delete operation
- You slow down because of extra operations
- You will have inconsistencies when the table is manipulated directly
- In MyISAM table the count is already retrieved as a field by MySQL
- In InnoDB it's a little slower, but subsequent calls are cached, so only the first one will be slow

Trying to do the work of a DBMS better than a DBMS is not a good idea. A DBMS embodies years and years of experience and optimisations.

Answer (score 2):

IMO you should always use MySQL internal functions to get results/data from your database.
But it depends also on what you're counting, which data you're retrieving, which operations you need to perform and so on.
Generally, if you can, use MySQL functions: they are fast and reliable!!

Answer (score 1):

I think in manual counting you would have to do it explicitly (write code) whereas if you use Mysql query it will be managed by the Mysql server... In the other case it would add extra overhead on the sever if its a webapp or something that you are building... I think going for sql count query would be wise!!!